# Regarding using History.js to manage browser state

Tags: jquery, browser-history, history.js

```
History.pushState(data,title,url)

History.pushState({state:1}, "State 1", "?state=1")
```

suppose if i need to store page number and sort order then what code i need to write?

url part is mandatory ?

how to get back the state when user click on browser back or forward buttons?

suppose i have a object like this

```
var PageState= {
    PageNo:1,
    SortCol:"Name",
    SortOrder:"ASC"
};
```

so can i store it like this way

```
History.pushState({state:PageState}, null, null); ?
```

when user click on browser back and forward button then how could i get back the state from browser history using `History.js lib` ?

looking for code sample. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL parameter is required because that's what gets appended to the base URL in the address bar. If you want to stay on the same path, but save a new history state, you could use the current url: `History.pushState(state, null, location.href)`.

The window emits an event when a history state is changed.

```
var PageState = {
    PageNo: 1,
    SortCol: "Name",
    SortOrder: "ASC"
};

History.pushState(PageState, null, location.href);

stateChangeHandler = function(event) {
    // This PageState is the same object defined above
    var PageState = event.state;
    var NewLocation = event.target.location.href;
};

// These two statements are nearly equivalent. Only one is needed.
window.onpopstate = stateChangeHandler;
window.addEventListener("popstate", stateChangeHandler);
```

Further reading: [MDN popstate reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate)